# Select only empty div's

Tags: jquery, css

I'm making a data table that has rows each with the class .table--grid--row being populated by a repeater field.  Not all rows have a value.  How can I change the background color of the rows that are an empty element?

```
 <div class="grid table--grid">
     <div class="table--grid--row grid__col u-bgColorOffWhite u-paddingVert2gu"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
     <div class="table--grid--row grid__col--4 u-textColorWhite u-bgColorTs21 u-paddingVert2gu"><?php echo $value; ?></div>
 </div>
```

This is what I've tried so far

```
 if ($(".table--grid--row").is(':empty')) {
    $(".table--grid--row").css("background-color", "white");
  }
```

but then it changes ALL rows.  I need to just change the rows that don't have a php $value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run an each loop on the element list and then check if `$(this).text() === ''`, then set the CSS using  `$(this).css('background', 'grey')`

```js
const $divEl = $('.table--grid--row')

$divEl.each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() === '') {
    $(this).css('background', 'grey')
  }
})
```

```css
.table--grid--row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table--grid--row grid__col u-bgColorOffWhite u-paddingVert2gu">This is not empty</div>
<div class="table--grid--row grid__col u-bgColorOffWhite u-paddingVert2gu">This has content</div>
<div class="table--grid--row grid__col u-bgColorOffWhite u-paddingVert2gu"></div>
<div class="table--grid--row grid__col u-bgColorOffWhite u-paddingVert2gu"></div>
<div class="table--grid--row grid__col u-bgColorOffWhite u-paddingVert2gu">This also has content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the text value using the below

```
$(".table--grid--row:empty").css('background-color','red'))
```

Comment: Hmm, seems like it should work but it won't.  
$(".table--grid--row").css("background-color", "white"); should go in the brackets presumably, right?